# Blank Page on mysqli_query();?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am making a basic song recommendation site, and I have a form set up that leads to a page with this exact code on it:

```
<?php
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        ob_start();
        session_start();

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "MYPASS";
        $db = "tts";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

        $song = $_POST['song'];
        $artist = $_POST['artist'];
        $album = $_POST['album'];
        $linkitunes = $_POST['linkitunes'];
        $artwork = $_POST['artwork'];

        $song = stripslashes($song);
        $artist = stripslashes($artist);
        $album = stripslashes($album);
        $linkitunes = stripslashes($linkitunes);
        $artwork = stripslashes($artwork);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO recommendation (user_id, song, artist, album, linkitunes, artwork, rating)";
        $sql = $sql . "VALUES ($_SESSION['id'], '$song', '$artist', '$album', '$linkitunes', '$artwork', '$rating');";

        print "Hello.";

        $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die("Fail");

        ob_flush();
?>
```

It always shows the "Hello." string until I add in the $sql value. I am thinking there is something wrong with the code syntax, but not sure. Have tried very many variations. Just in case, I have added the form code as well:

```
<form action="recommend-action.php" method="POST">
    <div id="noP" align="center">
            <h2>Make a new Recommendation</h2>
            <p>Please <a href="song-search.php">search</a> for your song before you recommend it.</p>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
            <input required name="song" type="text" placeholder="Song" maxlength="50"></input>
            <input required name="artist" type="text" placeholder="Artist" maxlength="50"></input>
            <input name="album" type="text" placeholder="Album" maxlength="50"></input>
            <input name="artwork" type="url" placeholder="Artwork" maxlength="500"></input>
            <input name="linkitunes" type="url" placeholder="Link in iTunes" maxlength="500"></input>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Recommend"></input>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am aware that I have not actually ran the SQL command.

Comment: $conn is missing in `mysqli_query`..

Comment: Enabling `error_reporting` in a file with syntax errors will not reveal much. Your file can't be parsed, so not even the error_reporting line will run. Enable it in your `php.ini`.

Comment: [`mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), notice the `$link`. Also, `mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )` can be your friend, ie. ` $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Also, php arrays, with named keys wrapped in single quotes, inside double quotes need to be wrapped in brackets ->`{$_SESSION['id']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should execute this...

```
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); or die("Fail");
```

Comment: I have changed that, but the page is still completely blank.

Comment: @CameronMontesano  actually what do you want acheive in this page ?

Comment: Had to change things, but it is the most help out of all the other answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications to your code, try this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ob_start();
session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "MYPASS";
$db = "tts";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$song = $_POST['song'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$album = $_POST['album'];
$linkitunes = $_POST['linkitunes'];
$artwork = $_POST['artwork'];

$song = stripslashes($song);
$artist = stripslashes($artist);
$album = stripslashes($album);
$linkitunes = stripslashes($linkitunes);
$artwork = stripslashes($artwork);

$sql = "INSERT INTO recommendation (user_id, song, artist, album, linkitunes, artwork, rating)";
$sql = $sql . "VALUES (".$_SESSION['id'].", '$song', '$artist', '$album', '$linkitunes', '$artwork', '$rating');";
        print "Hello.";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Fail");
        ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Just did that, page is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

You DO NOT have any line in PHP that gets converted to HTML... How will it display anything on screen. Write this at the end of your code.

```
echo "<br> Inserted Successfully";
```

The syntax of mysqli_query is wrong.
Use the following one.

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ("Fail");
```

Other possible Checks:

First Check your username and password and check if the connection to the database is successful by using this piece of code.

```
if (!$conn) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
```

Use session_start() as the first line of your code or else your sessions will not work. This is not needed but may cause you a problem in future.

Comment: What are you trying to display ? Your PHP code doesn't contain any line that gets converted to HTML.